# To migrate from kde3.5 to D-Bus

Tags: linux

I am new in this, but i have the next questions:

What is the difference between Kde4 and D-BUS? and

I have to migrate from kDE 3.5 to D-Bus, but i dont know what have to i do..

I hope that someone help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to install DBus in order to run KDE4. That's distribution specific, and we don't know what exactly you're running. There's the [retag](https://superuser.com/posts/310872/edit?tagsonly=true) button at the bottom of your post; you should use it to give us more information.

---

Anyhow, definitions:

Snagged from Wikipedia:

> In computing, D-Bus (Desktop Bus) is a simple inter-process communication (IPC) system for software applications to communicate with one another.

And for KDE:

> KDE ( /ˌkeɪdiːˈiː/) is an international free software community producing an integrated set of cross-platform applications designed to run on Linux, FreeBSD, Microsoft Windows, Solaris and Mac OS X systems.